# Building a "configuration package"

Tags: setup, apt, packages

I recently got a raspberry pi which I intend to use for some photography timelapsing/post processing while I'm on the road...

I've gotten the system setup now (albeit with some hassle) but I'd like to bundle everything together so that others could easily use/install my setup.

I think I have a couple of options but not sure what the best approach is.

1. Take an image of the pre-configured OS on the SD card and host it somewhere (right now it's a 32GB card so win32DiskImager is making a pretty big file... not sure it's feasible to host)
2. Stick everything in a github repo... basically a simple shell script + some of the replacement binaries for the accesspoint to work with realtek chip sets, so someone could just clone the repo, run a bash script and it would apt-get & setup Gphoto2, dhcp, wifi accesspoint, ssh, /etc/network/interfaces, and the various conf. files.
3. Make my own apt-get package... (not sure what's involved in this or how you go about getting your package approved hosted in the various apt-get repositories/mirrors)

Any suggestions on best-practice approaches would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1, You can delete unneeded stuff, zero free space, and 7z the IMG down to 100MB+

2, Less robust than option 1, but more flexible, and you won't have to update your stuff as often.

3, A package should not break any other, so if you are "replacing binaries" be sure to use alternatives. packages should also be fairly un-intrusive compared to the other options don't modify the files of other packages etc.

Try starting with option 2;

```
wget http://github.com/mysetup.sh && bash mysetup.sh
```

Comment: cheers for the input